# This program in java doesn't stop executing

Tags: java

I have written this java program for sorting some numbers. But it doesn't stop executing. Can you help me with it?

```
package inplacesort;

import java.util.*;

public class InplaceSort 
{
    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Vector <Integer> intList = new Vector <Integer> ();

        //getting the numbers from the user
        char ans = 'y';

        while (ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y')
        {
            System.out.print("Enter a Number: ");
            intList.addElement(console.nextInt());

            System.out.print("Do You Want to Continue?(Y/N)");
            ans = console.next().charAt(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Before Sorting the Numbers: " + intList);
        for (int i = 1; i < intList.size(); i++)
        {
            int j = i - 1;
            while (j > 0 && intList.elementAt(i) < intList.elementAt(j))
            {
                j--;
            }

            for (int k = intList.size() - 1; k >= j; k--)
            {
                intList.insertElementAt(intList.elementAt(k),k + 1);
            }

            intList.insertElementAt(intList.elementAt(i+1),j);
            intList.removeElementAt(i+1);
        }
        System.out.print(intList);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you step through it, line by line, with a debugger?  If you don't know how to use a debugger...learn how to use a debugger. It'll save you millions of these sorts of questions.

Comment: I give some numbers to it. When I press any other keys except 'y' or 'Y' it keeps wanting me to write things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with intList.size() in the k & i loops. This is not be as what you would expect it. When I debugged your code the value of k was 425996.

Edit :

When i debugged it more I saw that because of you mutating the vector within it self it keeps increasing in size. If you let your program run for a few minutes you will get out of memory error.

Please don't mutate the object you are looping though it. Either make a copy of it and the loop though one of them and mutate another or start with a fresh one & keep adding the values to it while looping over the older one.

```
        System.out.println("Before Sorting the Numbers: " + intList);
        List<Integer> sortList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int minVal;
        int index=0;
        int size = intList.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {   minVal=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for (int j = 0; j < intList.size(); j++)
            {
                if(intList.get(j) < minVal){
                    index=j;
                    minVal=intList.get(j);
                }
            }
            intList.remove(index);
            sortList.add(minVal);
        }
        System.out.print("After Sorting the Numbers: "+ sortList);
```

Comment: I am solving a problem and it has indicated that sort the numbers in increasing order without making a new object. Can you explain more how I can fix it?

Comment: Suggestions : Don't mutate the object you are looping though it. Either make a copy of it and the loop though one of them and mutate another or start with a fresh one & keep adding the values to it while looping over the older one.

Comment: @Parisa please check the answer for a possible solution or an approach...

Answer (score -1):

The reason is because your value for j  is ALWAYS 1 less than the value for i.  Therefore, infinite while loop.

Comment: Which loop would be infinite because of that?

Comment: Can you specify what do you mean and how I must fix it?